# Cannot create a rclcpp::spin function

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am having a trouble in publishing and subscribing the node at the same time. More specifically, I am having an issue to pass the shared_ptr to the rclcpp::spin function. Here is my function inside my class:

```
void OdomNode::update()
{
    //std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> _for_spin = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(*this);
    while(rclcpp::ok())
    {
        this->loop();
        this->_loop_rate.sleep();
        rclcpp::spin(*this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the object itself inherits from rclcpp::Node class and this is a node instance. I have tried to use the first (uncommented) choice but it would not compile saying that the variable is private in this context (not sure what private there exactly). I have also tried to pass shared_from_this but during the runtime it crashes saying that it is a bad_weak_ptr.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330273/cannot-create-a-rclcpp::spin-function/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@jdlangs is correct that `shared_from_this()` is the correct way to get a shared pointer to the node.

Besides the compilation issue, your code looks troublesome. `rclcpp::spin()` is a blocking function, so `this->loop()` will only be called once. You could try using `rclcpp::spin_some()` instead, but I suggest that you call `rclcpp::spin()` from outside your node, for example in a `main` function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  auto odom_node = std::make_shared<OdomNode>();
  rclcpp::spin(odom_node);

  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

And perhaps start a timer to replace your update method, for example in the constructor:

```
OdomNode::OdomNode(rclcpp::Duration & loop_rate)
{
  timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(loop_rate.to_chrono(), std::bind(&OdomNode::loop, this));
}
```

This is the pattern you'll find in many of the [examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/master/rclcpp) and [demos](https://github.com/ros2/demos).
This helps make your node more flexible. For example, it leaves open the possibility to compose your node with others into a single process, or easily change the type of executor or callback group.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using `shared_from_this()` is the correct way to obtain a `rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr`. But note that it only works if there already exists a `shared_ptr` that has ownership of the node. If you had only created a local `OdomNode` object instead of using `std::make_shared`, you would get that `bad_weak_ptr` error.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2019-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2